# Form with multiple rows/entity in Symfony

Tags: symfony

I am using Symfony 6 and created an entity for global options and so the sql table has only 3 columns : **name**, **label** and **value**

In order to store global info about my app. Like this.

| id | name | label | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | maintenance | Set the app in maintenance | 0 |
| 2 | allow_comments | Allow comments for products | 1 |

How can I make a form which contains every elements of the table ?

I would like the result to be like this : [Expected form result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3cKt.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: You are asking a very broad question and I even wonder how you have a web application at all to configure if you can't do a crud for such a simple entity. Despite being simple it involves too much stuff and you should learn from symfony doc and come back with more specific questions

Answer (score 1):

As you have a table (so it's an entity I guess) `CollectionType` is a way to go.

```php
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
// ...

$builder->add('emails', CollectionType::class, [
    // each entry in the array will be an "email" field
    'entry_type' => EmailType::class,
    // these options are passed to each "email" type
    'entry_options' => [
        'attr' => ['class' => 'email-box'],
    ],
]);
```

As the `entry_type` you can just pass `EntityType`.

Ref: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read my question.
Indeed I have an entity `GlobalOption`. I couldn't understand how I can apply your example to my needs though. I know this is a simple crud operation, but I am used to process only one row of the table.. Thanks anyway !

Comment: @lccsc as the `entry_type` you can pass `EntityType:class`. Then in the `entry_options` you can configure it. Ref: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html